# The 'remote' tag migrating from Prototype to jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I am migrating from Prototype to jQuery 1.6.1.

In my application I have a lot of input forms that make use of the `remote` tag in order to submit data using JavaScript:

```
# A form example in my application
<%= form_for(@user, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

To fix this problem, in my `app/views/application.html.erb` file, I tried to change the code from this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, 'jquery-1.6.1.min' %>
```

to this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.6.1.min', 'application' %>
```

However, the `remote` tag doesn't work anymore with my forms (which is normal behavior since RoR use custom Prototype helper methods).

Is there an "*easy*" way to handle forms using JavaScript without Prototype and to avoid the above problem with the `remote` tag? If so, what do I have to do?

---

In the case, I must use Prototype to "solve"\"support" this problem, can I "delete"\"not load" in my `public/javascript` folder some of the following files?

```
application.js
controls.js    
dragdrop.js
effects.js
jquery-1.6.1.min.js
prototype.js
rails.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Rails to use jQuery.

Add `gem jquery-rails` to your Gemfile, and run `rails g jquery:install`.

See [the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/jquery-rails/1.0.9/frames) for more information.

Comment: (1) After I installed that gem, can I still use the 'remote' tag for my forms without editing each of them code in files? (2) Can I use Prototype helper methods as jQuery helper methods? Will be the mentioned 'jquery-rails' the default JavaScript framework in the Rails 3.1 release? (3) Running the 'rails g jquery:install' command will automatically handle all installation issues and will be my application still a "stable\working system" after the installation?

Comment: Furthermore, the documentation is still not enough goods on the web.

Answer (score 0):

When submitting the form, does a new page load or does a request happen via Ajax? Use Firefox+Firebug to check that the call is really an Ajax call.

Second, you need to check that your layout correctly loads jQuery and the [jQuery Rails connector](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs). Visit this link for a more detailed instruction depending on what version of Rails you are using.